# ViaCEP não preenche dados de endereço do usuário (Website na plataforma .NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web na plataforma .NET e pensei em fazer com que o usuário digite o cep de seu endereço e automaticamente ele preencheria os textboxs com dados de logradouro, bairro, cidade e estado. Mas no meu código ele não funciona, não sei porque.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="insert.aspx.cs" Inherits="insert" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Novo Registro</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
            $("#txtCPF").keydown(function(){
                try {
                    $("#txtCPF").unmask();
                } catch (e) {}

                var tamanho = $("#txtCPF").val().length;

                if(tamanho < 11){
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
                } else if(tamanho >= 11){
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
                }                   
            });
        }//]]> 
</script>
    <!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function limpa_formulario_cep() {
            //Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
            document.getElementById("#txtRua").value=("");
            document.getElementById('#txtBairro').value=("");
            document.getElementById('#txtCidade').value=("");
            document.getElementById('#txtEstado').value=("");
    }

    function meu_callback(conteudo) {
        if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
            //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
            document.getElementById('#txtRua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
            document.getElementById('#txtBairro').value = (conteudo.bairro);
            document.getElementById('#txtCidade').value = (conteudo.localidade);
            document.getElementById('#txtEstado').value = (conteudo.uf);
        } //end if.
        else {
            //CEP não Encontrado.
            limpa_formulario_cep();
            alert("CEP não encontrado.");
        }
    }

    function pesquisacep(valor) {
        //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
        var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');

        //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
        if (cep != "") {

            //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
            var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

            //Valida o formato do CEP.
            if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
                document.getElementById('#txtRua').value = "...";
                document.getElementById('#txtBairro').value = "...";
                document.getElementById('#txtCidade').value = "...";
                document.getElementById('#txtEstado').value = "...";

                //Cria um elemento javascript.
                var script = document.createElement('script');

                //Sincroniza com o callback.
                script.src = '//viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';

                //Insere script no documento e carrega o conteúdo.
                document.body.appendChild(script);

            } //end if.
            else {
                //cep é inválido.
                limpa_formulario_cep();
                alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
            }
        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
            limpa_formulario_cep();
        }
    };

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3>Cadastro de Clientes - Novo Registro</h3>
        <h5>Obs.: Campos sinalizados com *(asterisco) são de preenchimento obrigatório!</h5>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome" runat="server" Width="384px" placeholder="Nome*"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtNomeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFantasia" runat="server" Width="384px" placeholder="Fantasia"></asp:TextBox><br /> 

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCPF" runat="server" Width="384px" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCEP" runat="server" Width="70px" placeholder="CEP*" AutopostBack="true"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogradouro" runat="server" Width="305px" placeholder="Logradouro"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumero" runat="server" Width="80px" placeholder="Número"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComplemento" runat="server" Width="100px" placeholder="Complemento"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBairro" runat="server" Width="200px" placeholder="Bairro"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCidade" runat="server" Width="200px" placeholder="Cidade"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEstado" runat="server" Width="50px" placeholder="Estado"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Button ID="btnSalvar" runat="server" Text="Salvar"/>

       </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

meu code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class insert : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCEP.Attributes.Add("onblur", "pesquisacep(this.value);");
    }

}
```

Ele funciona no JSBIN:
http://output.jsbin.com/baxuyumace

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa, por favor?

Comment: Ola Cássia, seja bem vinda ao Stackoverflow em Português. Vc poderia ser mais especifica, porque não funciona? Existe alguma mensagem de erro? Tente isolar mais o problema.

Comment: Obrigada, drmcarvalho :). Então, eu vou pra digitar o CEP e a tela atualiza, mas os campos não são preenchidos :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="insert.aspx.cs" Inherits="insert" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Novo Registro</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
            $("#txtCPF").keydown(function(){
                try {
                    $("#txtCPF").unmask();
                } catch (e) {}

                var tamanho = $("#txtCPF").val().length;

                if(tamanho < 11){
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
                } else if(tamanho >= 11){
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
                }                   
            });
        }//]]> 
    </script>
    <!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        $(document).ready(function() {

            function limpa_formulario_cep() {
                // Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
                $("#txtLogradouro").val("");
                $("#txtBairro").val("");
                $("#txtCidade").val("");
                $("#txtEstado").val("");
            }

            //Quando o campo cep perde o foco.
            $("#txtCEP").blur(function() {

                //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
                var cep = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

                //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
                if (cep != "") {

                    //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
                    var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

                    //Valida o formato do CEP.
                    if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                        //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
                        $("#txtLogradouro").val("...")
                        $("#txtBairro").val("...")
                        $("#txtCidade").val("...")
                        $("#txtEstado").val("...")

                        //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
                        $.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                            if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                                //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                                $("#txtLogradouro").val(dados.logradouro);
                                $("#txtBairro").val(dados.bairro);
                                $("#txtCidade").val(dados.localidade);
                                $("#txtEstado").val(dados.uf);
                            } //end if.
                            else {
                                //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                                limpa_formulario_cep();
                                alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                            }
                        });
                    } //end if.
                    else {
                        //cep é inválido.
                        limpa_formulario_cep();
                        alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
                    }
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
                    limpa_formulario_cep();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3>Cadastro de Clientes - Novo Registro</h3>
        <h5>Obs.: Campos sinalizados com *(asterisco) são de preenchimento obrigatório!</h5>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome" runat="server" Width="384px" placeholder="Nome*"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtNomeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFantasia" runat="server" Width="384px" placeholder="Fantasia"></asp:TextBox><br /> 

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCPF" runat="server" Width="384px" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCEP" runat="server" Width="70px" placeholder="CEP*" AutopostBack="true" AcceptsTab="True"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogradouro" runat="server" Width="305px" placeholder="Logradouro"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumero" runat="server" Width="80px" placeholder="Número"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComplemento" runat="server" Width="100px" placeholder="Complemento"  AutopostBack="true"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBairro" runat="server" Width="200px" placeholder="Bairro"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCidade" runat="server" Width="200px" placeholder="Cidade"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEstado" runat="server" Width="50px" placeholder="Estado"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Button ID="btnSalvar" runat="server" Text="Salvar"/>

       </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Consegui resolver. Pra quem tiver interesse, o código está aí.

Comment: marca como resolvido a sua propria resposta :)

Comment: @Cássia, se você mesma conseguiu resolver, você pode marcar a sua própria resposta como resolvida para que outras pessoas consigam tirar proveito da solução ;)

Comment: Obrigada, amigos. Já marquei a minha resposta. Espero continuar a contribuir com a comunidade. bjs

Comment: @Cássia gostei do código, obrigado por compartilhar!

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizo o próprio Serviço dos Correios.

Exemplo de Consumo:

```
            using (var ws = new AtendeClienteClient())
        {
            var resposta = ws.consultaCEP(cep);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Endereço : {0}", resposta.end));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Bairro : {0}", resposta.bairro));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Cidade : {0}", resposta.cidade));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("UF : {0}", resposta.uf));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("CEP : {0}", resposta.cep));
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("PRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARA CONTINUAR...");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

O WSDL pode ser encontrado em:
[WSDL Correios](https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl)

Exemplo de importação e implementação em C#:
[Exemplo em C#](https://github.com/rogermedeirosdasilva/Exemplos/tree/master/VSBS_WS_Cep)

Vídeo Explicativo:

[Exemplo no YouTube](https://youtu.be/jg4jxh3668Y)

Comment: Roger, sua resposta é ótima, porém o conteúdo não fica no StackOverflow, teria como editar e adicionar o código, e então mencionar o tutorial [Consumindo WebService dos Correios - CEP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg4jxh3668Y&feature=youtu.be), e seu repositório no Git, etc.

Comment: David o código é o simples consumo do WS. Acredito que o interessante é o WSDL do correio que não é conhecido de todos.